# Unix Shell script to copy files from unix location to windows FTP

Tags: unix

Could anyone provide me Unix shell script to copy files from unix location to windows FTP location.

Thanks,

Chaitu

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; do you want to use a unix `$cp file dest/` command or you want to FTP from the Unix box to the Windows box?

Comment: @AI G: I want to FTP from unix box to window box after USA business hours.

Comment: *"Could anyone provide me..."*: This site is not a service that writes code on-demand - its a Q&A site. What did you try? What is your *question*?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you have access to the unix box. Sounds like a simple [cron](http://www.scrounge.org/linux/cron.html) job using ftp. You'll need to review the crontab syntax to set that up. Check out [this article on scripting FTP](http://www.stratigery.com/scripting.ftp.html) to get you started there.